# All paths between two nodes neo4j - incorrect answer (from neo4j)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to get all path between two nodes with the relation "->" between them.
I ask my DB using query (Cypher) like that:

```
START a=node(27), b=node(0) MATCH p=b<-[*]-a RETURN p
```

In Neo4j visualization I get this:

[Cypher query visualization](https://hubic.com/home/pub/?ruid=aHR0cHM6Ly9sYjEuaHViaWMub3ZoLm5ldC92MS9BVVRIXzYyMDJjZTM1Y2VkNDMyMzBmMjk4YWNlYzZkNDEyYmJkL2RlZmF1bHQvLm92aFB1Yi8xMzkyODQ4OTMxXzEzOTU0NDA5MzE/dGVtcF91cmxfc2lnPWRiNjQwNjMzY2VjNzRlNWYyMzZjZjlkMzBjYTg3NTAxZDUwNWZhMWUmdGVtcF91cmxfZXhwaXJlcz0xMzk1NDQwOTMx#)

I want to get list of 3 path:

- 27 -> 81 -> .... -> 0
- 27 -> 67 -> .... -> 0
- 27 -> 24 -> .... -> 0

but  in the result I have got 6 paths (instead of 3). 
I want to figure out why.

Comment: Can you create a graphgist of this?  Easier to play around

Comment: Can you provide the 6 paths in the result ?

Comment: The result was to long to put in in comment so here is link to it: https://hubic.com/home/pub/?ruid=aHR0cHM6Ly9sYjEuaHViaWMub3ZoLm5ldC92MS9BVVRIXzYyMDJjZTM1Y2VkNDMyMzBmMjk4YWNlYzZkNDEyYmJkL2RlZmF1bHQvLm92aFB1Yi8xMzkyODgyMzY1XzEzOTM3NDYzNjU/dGVtcF91cmxfc2lnPWYyYzA3ZjBiN2Q5YmQyMTY0ZjdlNjYzNzI3MDFhZWViM2UyNjI1ZjImdGVtcF91cmxfZXhwaXJlcz0xMzkzNzQ2MzY1#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the query includes the 0 length paths starting from 'a'. If you look at the file you provided, the last three results are the same as the first three ones, except for the duplication of Node[0] at the beginning of the path.

Comment: I dont understand why query includes the 0 length paths starting from 'a'. It is impossible to go from 'a' to 'b' in path with length 0 
Could you explain it to me clearly?
How should looks like query to give 3 paths?

Comment: You can read here about the 0 length paths: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/1.9.6/query-match.html#match-zero-length-paths

The query for 3 paths should be something like: START a=node(27), b=node(0) MATCH p=b<-[1..3]-a RETURN p

Comment: I'm not sure that you are right. I think that you have in mind [*1..3] not [1..3] according to http://docs.neo4j.org/refcard/2.0/. That means that you want to get path with length between 1 and 3. I checked my path lengths and first 3 was 6, 7, 7 and the next 3 was 7,8,8. I still have no idea how to query to get what I want.

Comment: Yes, I forgot the *, so you're rigth is [*1..n]. Having n=7 or 8 doesn't solve your problem ?

Comment: It don't solve my problem because I don't know path length (it depends of graph). I saw another strange thing in the file with path which i have provided. Relation between nodes (e.g. in 4 line) aren't connected with nodes in graph. In 1. line subClassOf is 43 - it is correct (43 is connected with 0), but in the 4. subClassOf is 35 and it is not connected with 'node 0'

Comment: Have you tried the 'allShortestPaths' ? http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/2.0.1/query-match.html#_shortest_path

Comment: allShortestPath it is not what I need (i need all path, not only the shortest).
I have found what was the problem - I have got error in my neo4j graph: loop relation from 'node 0' to 'node 0'.
Thank you for your help in the investigation to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your `(OwlThing)` has a `[:subClassOf]` relationship to itself. It doesn't show in the visualisation, but that's what

```
Node[0]{name:"owl:Thing"},:subClassOf[35]{},Node[0]{name:"owl:Thing"}
```

in your results means. For every path from that ends with `(41)-[43]->(0)` there is also a `(41)-[43]->(0)-[35]->(0)` which means your results are doubled.