# duplicated one node in path - cypher (query all path between two nodes)

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher, node-neo4j

I have got nodes connected like in the picture from the [link](https://hubic.com/home/pub/?ruid=aHR0cHM6Ly9sYjEuaHViaWMub3ZoLm5ldC92MS9BVVRIXzYyMDJjZTM1Y2VkNDMyMzBmMjk4YWNlYzZkNDEyYmJkL2RlZmF1bHQvLm92aFB1Yi8xMzkyODQ4OTMxXzEzOTU0NDA5MzE/dGVtcF91cmxfc2lnPWRiNjQwNjMzY2VjNzRlNWYyMzZjZjlkMzBjYTg3NTAxZDUwNWZhMWUmdGVtcF91cmxfZXhwaXJlcz0xMzk1NDQwOTMx#)

I do query `START a=node(27), b=node(0) MATCH p=b<-[*]-a RETURN p`

I expect that I will get 3 paths but got 6.
First 3 are correct but the last 3 have got duplicate 'node 0'

For example:

correct path: 0 -> 41 -> 2 -> ... -> 27 
duplicate node path: 0 -> 0 -> 41 -> 2 -> 27

The lengths of incorrect paths are exactly incremented by one.

How to write a query to get (in this example) exactly 3 path without duplicate nodes?

Comment: Do you have self loops on `node 0` in the data?

Comment: I don't have, or I don't know about it. Do you know how can I check it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [All paths between two nodes neo4j - incorrect anwser (from neo4j)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21894026/all-paths-between-two-nodes-neo4j-incorrect-anwser-from-neo4j)

Comment: I have checked it and you was right MarcoCI. I have got self loop on node 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is correct and there probably is a problem in the database. I replicated your graph structure: [console.neo4j](http://console.neo4j.org/r/4pspcp). Run `START n=node(*) RETURN n` to get the ids of node 27 and 0 and then run your query. It returns exactly 3 results.


To check whether you have loops on node 0 execute:

```
START n=node(0) MATCH n-[r]-n RETURN r
```

Comment: I have checked it in console and you are right. Do you know some semiautomatic way of moving data from my local database to console.neo4j.org to test my real database?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I added a way to check for self loops to the answer.

Comment: You can "dump" your database from neo4j-shell, see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/shell-commands.html#_dumping_the_database_or_a_cypher_result_to_cypher_statements

Comment: I had self loop on node 0. I had removed it and everything is OK. Thanks you for helping.

I cannot vote up your answer because I don't have got 15 reputation points.

Comment: Since you asked the question and the answer solved it for you then you  can mark it as accepted.